# How to create a symbolic link of most recent file in a folder into another folder

Tags: macos, shell, bsd

I would like to create a bash script for osx systems. This script should select some recent files and then link those in a specific folder. My requirements is to create all the links in a flat directory instead of create the original path of each file in the target folder.

I thought something like that (something wrong in the sintax):

```
find ~/Documents/ -type f -mtime -10 \( -name "*.pdf" -or -name "*.doc" \)  -exec ln -s {} $(basename {} ) \;
```

Comment: Solved! The correct sintax is:find ~/Documents/ -type f -mtime -10 \( -name "*.pdf" -or -name "*.doc" \)  -exec ln -s {}  \;